# c#.net problem doing Page_unloading

Tags: c#

i m using c#.net and in the page_load event i m writing writing..and it should be destroyed when page_unload occurs.but when i am doing debugging both page_load and page_unload event triggered which was not supposed to be done. like in servlet it runs.

so plz help me i want that doing navigating to other pages i want first when view in browser page_load triggered the navigating to other page_unloading should be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page lifecycle on the server side does ahere with any client side events. If you want to react on the document load event on client side, you have to write javascript code.

The Page_Unload event is triggered right before the page is sent to the client. If you need an event, which tells you that the document was closed on client side, you will have to use a javascript event.

This should give you an idea of what to do:

```
<body onunload="__doPostBack('','unloading');" />
```

If you want to hava a professional implementation hava a look at AjaxControlToolkit. Create a new ScriptControl and use the integrated Callback mechanism.

Comment: its true for handing client site and for reducing the laod on server we use javascript. suppose i m added one image file in one folder.and want to delete when when signout.the problem occurs when when i m retrieving that image and deleting the path in

Comment: If you delete an image in Page_Unloading, this will happen BEFORE the page is sent to the browser. Thus the image will not be available when the page is displayed.

Comment: yes your last comment is exactly what my problem is. so what should i do. i want my image should be available during loading.when i moved to other page the it should call page_unload and delete the image from that folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the ASP.Net page life cycle first. Better read the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: i know c#.net and i had worked already for one the website. but the problem is different plz read my question carefully

Comment: " i am doing debugging both page_load and page_unload event triggered which was not supposed to be done" 
Both the events will be triggered, as Page_Unload is the last event triggered.

Comment: its true for handing client site and for reducing the laod on server we use javascript. suppose i m added one image file in one folder.and want to delete when when signout.the problem occurs when when i m retrieving that image and deleting the path in Page_unload. bt when i m debugging the the browser goes to page_load with page _unload and my image path deleted already before showning in my page.

Comment: yes that is occuring ..and this is the problem.it should be page_inload_the show my image then page_unload deleteing my image when when to other page.

Comment: probably what you want is not Page_Unload because it is not what you think it is. I believe you think that Page Unload is called when you move away from page... hmm.. if yes, then you are wrong. 

You can achieve what you want using javascript - onUnload event. Provide like this:
<BODY onUnload="deletePage()">

Where in deletePage method you can provide the code for deleting the image.

Answer (score 0):

As standard a web page will not notify the server when a user navigates away from the page. The way it works is when you make a request on the server an object is created for your page. It fires all the events you want such as load. Once it has done everything and sent its content to the client the page object on the server is no longer needed so it is removed and in the process fires its unload event. Once the browser processes the page the unload has already fired and your image path has been destroyed.

What you will want to do is either have an image handler that can deal with whatever image cleanup is needed after the request or a javascript solution as others have indicated to notify the server when the page is unloaded.

Comment: quite right..but i just want the page_unload should not be happened with the page_load.The page_unLoad should be called after the all the work not during alongwith page_unload which i foung during debugging.because if its happen what the need of Page_unload